# Can't get the Euro symbol (€) to display in a phpword-generated docx

Tags: php, character-encoding, phpword

I can't get the Euro symbol (€) to display in a generated .docx. All I get is a square shape.

My first thought is it's an encoding issue, but there's no encoding specified anywhere in my script. I've specified charsets for HTML pages and in SQL databases for other projects (UTF8 would do it) but the implementation in question uses neither.

Another thing that occurs to me is that the docx gets created **on the server**, and is downloaded from there for printing. Could the server environment be to blame? I can't see any way to change encoding for the docx when it's online.

Ideally I'd like an in-document fix rather than getting the hosting company to tinker with settings.

This is the code:

```
$textrun->addText('If you wish to have a script remarked we will charge €35 for this.);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$fa_euro = html_entity_decode('&#xf153;', 0, 'UTF-8');
$section->addText(utf8($fa_euro));
```

Google is your friend: 
https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/780

Also on the top of the script set this:

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
```

Comment: are you using the latest version of phpword?

Comment: Yes. .json file is 

"require": {
"phpoffice/phpword": "v0.13.*"
}
}

Comment: When you apply the solution from my answer, what does it display?

Comment: Try:  mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8"); on the top of the script.

Comment: I tried the mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8"); but it didn't work. Still getting the square.

Btw, I deleted a previous comment because I was wrong in what I wrote. I was mixing up your utf8($fa_euro) suggestion with another one I had tried. Anyway, neither works for me.

Comment: When I add mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8") it does change the encoding, since if I do an echo mb_internal_encoding() it outputs UTF-8 and when I remove the mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8") it outputs ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136881/discussion-between-klaatu-verata-necto-and-user2304574).

Answer (score 1):

Although this answer might come late, it might be of use to those who still encounter difficulties related to this issue.

A short and simple solution would be to use PHP's **utf8_decode()** function, which converts a string into UTF-8 format ([PHP Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php)).

When passed a UTF-8 format string while assigning a value in the PHPWord Document, special characters including currency symbols, German characters with umlauts will be inserted properly in the document.

Example:

```
$PHPWord = new PHPWord();
$document = $PHPWord->loadTemplate('template.docx');

$document->setValue('variable', utf8_decode($value));
```

A special case scenario is when editing your script through Nano (CLI editor) in certain Linux distributions - if you have hardcoded any strings containing special characters they will be converted to another encoding upon saving the file.

Edit: Be cautious when using the **htmlspecialchars** function without a third parameter on legacy systems as the parameter's default value is different depending on the PHP version ([PHP 5.4 Compatibility](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.incompatible.php)).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that when I get back to the office in 3 weeks time. I never resolved the issue and inserted a graphic as a workaround.

Comment: Did you manage to implement this solution? If it solved your problem please accept the answer. People stumble upon this issue often :)

Answer (score 0):

phpword don't support special symbol like & or < or > etc.. for solve it i've used this:

```
$n = htmlspecialchars("your string with special chars");
$section->addText($n);
```